# Nvidia module doesn't load correctly (i have to reload it by hand to log in)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

My system is 16.04 LTS since 2016...
After the last update, Ubuntu fails to start X (through lightdm).
However 'nvidia module' is loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia                13819904  0
drm                   364544    4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia
```

Modules seems to be installed correctly

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
# This file was installed by nvidia-387
# Do not edit this file manually

blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
blacklist nvidia-current
blacklist nvidia-173
blacklist nvidia-96
blacklist nvidia-current-updates
blacklist nvidia-173-updates
blacklist nvidia-96-updates
blacklist nvidia-387-updates
alias nvidia nvidia_387
alias nvidia-uvm nvidia_387_uvm
alias nvidia-modeset nvidia_387_modeset
alias nvidia-drm nvidia_387_drm
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off

options nvidia_387_drm modeset=0
```

I have to unload it and reload it manually to launch X...

```
$ sudo service lightdm stop
$ sudo rmmod nvidia
$ sudo modprobe nvidia
$ lsmod | grep nv
nvidia_uvm            675840  0
nvidia_drm             49152  1
nvidia_modeset        897024  5 nvidia_drm
nvidia              13819904  319 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   364544  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm

$ sudo service lightdm start
```

And it works...

The strange thing is that ubuntu load nvidia modules without drm,modeset and uvm...

So, how to set ubuntu in order it load modules correctly  ?